# Time derivative of spherical unit vector

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems

I want to find time derivative of $\hat \phi $ ($(r,\theta, \phi)$ of spherical coordinates).
I know that, 
$$\hat \phi = -\sin \phi \hat i +  \cos \phi \hat j .$$
It is only a function of $\phi $. Now, $$\frac {d \hat \phi} {dt}= \frac {d \hat \phi} {d \phi}\cdot \frac {d \phi} {dt} = - \cos \phi \hat i -  \sin \phi \hat j .\frac {d\phi} {dt}$$
How to express in terms of $\hat r$ and $\hat \theta$?

Comment: What happened to the $d\phi/dt$ in the last expression?

Comment: Do you know how to express $\hat r$ and $\hat\theta$ in terms of $\hat i$ and $\hat j$? If so, solve these two equations for $\hat i$ and $\hat j$.

Comment: G. Smith your technique worked